# Google Action : Transactions not available on all devices

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've implemented the Transactions API for the Google Assistant Action. The Action is deployed and published to the public. (So it has been tested by the Google review team.)

There are some devices that aren't supporting transactions. But not all the time. For example the Google Nest Hub. Sometimes it says it isn't able to transact and sometime it does, this differs by user. Which is weird. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Is there a user setting or something we need to change?

Comment: Are you using the `TransactionRequirementsCheck` helper before building the transaction?

Comment: Yes i am. And with some devices it returns CAN_TRANSACT and some not. The weird thing is that it differs on user rather then on device type. 2 Google Hubs give different results

Comment: That's the point of `TransactionRequirementsCheck`. Google does some checking on the background to see if a transaction can occur. That means, the device, the application, the user all have to be able to perform a Transaction. I can't say for sure but I think it may be happening due to some user setting on the Google Hub device